# Cannot remove /log/var/snort as root

Tags: permissions, root, rm

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 Gnome.

I uninstalled snort in order to install a more recent version.  The new installation initially failed because the system would not let be rm or modify /var/log/snort even as root.

```
sudo chattr -i /var/log/snort/*
```

enabled me to remove the contents of /var/log/snort although the i attribute did not appear to have been set.

However `sudo chattr -i /var/log/snort`
did not allow me to remove `/var/log/snort` itself although only the e attribute was set.

I was able to change ownership of `/var/log/snort` but that does not help

```
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ ls -ld /var/log/snort
drwxrws--- 2 root adm 4096 2013-05-20 23:22 /var/log/snort
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ sudo rmdir /var/log/snort
[sudo] password for peter: 
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/log/snort': Operation not permitted
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ sudo rm -rf /var/log/snort
rm: cannot remove `/var/log/snort': Operation not permitted
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ sudo chown peter /var/log/snort
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ ls -ld /var/log/snort
drwxrws--- 2 peter adm 4096 2013-05-20 23:22 /var/log/snort
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ rmdir /var/log/snort
rmdir: failed to remove `/var/log/snort': Permission denied
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$ rm -rf /var/log/snort
rm: cannot remove `/var/log/snort': Permission denied
peter-Inspiron-620:/var/log$
```

I tried rebooting the computer and going into the root shell in restore mode but was still unable to remove this directory.

Comment: Have you tried `fsck`ing the disk that the directory lives on?

Answer (score 1):

You can find out the current instances on the directory using the command

```
lsof +D /var/log/snort
```

This will help you to find out the current processes which are using files present in the directory you are searching for in your case it's `/var/log/snort`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if another process is accessing the file:

```
sudo fuser /var/log/snort
```